# how to edit an existing data in glib lists

Tags: c, linux, glib, doubly-linked-list

I use glib's lists (linked-lists) for storing a list of strings in my program. I'm already able to append, prepend or insert new items to the list but I can't edit an existing item in the list. I cannot find the appropriate function for editing items in glib's documentation. Is there any functions implemented in glib for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use the structure directly, as the internal structure is [exposed](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html#GList):

```
struct GList {
  gpointer data;
  GList *next;
  GList *prev;
};
```

So, for example:

```
GList *bar = g_list_last(foo);
bar->data = NULL; //for instance
```